# href a linked swfobject (without clicktag support)

Tags: html, flash, href

I have a swfobject and embeded a link on it's flash file .
when swf file have a inside link , can't set a custom link with href tag directly .

I try to link it with a overflow div link , but can't .

**Example :**

```
<a href="http://MyURL.com/MyTarget" target="_blank">
    <object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='MySWF.swf' width='468' height='60'>
        <param name='flashvars' value='clickTag=http://MyURL.com/MyTarget&clickTarget=_blank' />
        <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always' />
        <param name='movie' value='MySWF.swf' />
        <param name='bgcolor' value='#ffffff'>
    </object>
</a>
```

Short : How to set a custom link (href) on a swfobject with embeded link url .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**clean way** :

```
<a href="http://MyURL.com/MyTarget" target="_blank">
    <object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='MySWF.swf' width='468' height='60'>
        <param name='flashvars' value='clickTag=http://MyURL.com/MyTarget&clickTarget=_blank' />
        <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always' />
        <param name='movie' value='MySWF.swf' />
        <param name='bgcolor' value='#ffffff'>
    </object>
    <!-- add below i tag with this style can display a block over swf object -->
    <i style="display:block; height: 60px; width: 468px;  position: relative; z-index: 9; margin-top: -60px;"></i>
</a>
```